# For a continuous DV that ranges between 0 and 1, which of the gbm package's distributions would you recommend?

Tags: r, distributions, boosting

My DV consists of a variable ranging between 0 and 1 (it's a percentage to be more precise) and I am using the `gbm` package to predict it. 
Given the nature of my DV I am assuming that using a Laplace distribution, in order to minimize the absolute error, might be better than using a guassian distribution, which minimizes the squared error. However, I am not sure my assumption is correct and I would like to know whether in theory my assumption is correct.

Additionally, on a later stage I might be interested in defining a cut-off point, *x*, for binary classification. If I aim to do that, which of the following would be the best alternative (I'm open for additional suggestions of course):

- spliting the data beforehand into "high" and "low" values (e.g.
  `ifelse(DV > x, 1, 0)`) and treating it as a
  binary variable using **adaboost** or **bernouli** distributions
- staying with
  the original data and using a **quantile regression** with *x* as a cut-off
  point
- staying with the original data and using a **gaussian**/**laplace**
  distribution and defining *x* a posteriori.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Another possibility is to transform your variable eg by taking its logit so it takes up the whole space of real numbers.  Then least squares is likely to work quite well.  But I'm not familiar enough with gbm to give you a definitive answer.